# Problems with django testing?

Tags: python, django, django-views, pytest, pytest-django

I am developing a django app and currently testing it as well, this is my view:

```
from django.http import JsonResponse, HttpResponseBadRequest
from store.models import Product
from .basket import Basket


# Create your views here.
def basket_summary(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    return render(request, "store/basket/summary.html", {"basket": basket})


def basket_add(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get("action") == "post":
        product_id = int(request.POST.get("productid"))
        product_qty = int(request.POST.get("productqty"))
        product = get_object_or_404(Product, id=product_id)
        basket.add(product=product, product_qty=product_qty)

        basket_qty = basket.__len__()
        response = JsonResponse({"qty": basket_qty})
        return response


def basket_delete(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get("action") == "post":
        product_id = int(request.POST.get("productid"))
        basket.delete(product_id=product_id)

        basket_qty = basket.__len__()
        basket_total = basket.get_total_price()
        response = JsonResponse({"qty": basket_qty, "subtotal": basket_total})
        return response


def basket_update(request):
    basket = Basket(request)
    if request.POST.get("action") == "post":
        product_id = int(request.POST.get("productid"))
        product_qty = int(request.POST.get("productqty"))
        basket.update(product_id=product_id, product_qty=product_qty)

        basket_qty = basket.__len__()
        basket_total = basket.get_total_price()
        response = JsonResponse({"qty": basket_qty, "subtotal": basket_total})
        return response
```

My urls.py file is also below:

```
from .views import basket_summary, basket_add, basket_delete, basket_update

app_name = "store_basket"
urlpatterns = [
    path("", basket_summary, name="basket_summary"),
    path("add/", basket_add, name="basket_add"),
    path("delete/", basket_delete, name="basket_delete"),
    path("update/", basket_update, name="basket_update"),
]
```

Finally my testing file:

```
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from django.test import TestCase
from django.urls import reverse
from store.models import Category, Product
from json import loads


class TestBasketView(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        category = Category.objects.create(name="django", slug="django")
        user = User.objects.create(username="admin")
        Product.objects.create(
            title="django beginners",
            category=category,
            created_by=user,
            slug="django-beginners",
            price="20.00",
            image="django",
        )
        Product.objects.create(
            title="django intermediate",
            category=category,
            created_by=user,
            slug="django-beginners",
            price="20.00",
            image="django",
        )
        Product.objects.create(
            title="django advanced",
            category=category,
            created_by=user,
            slug="django-beginners",
            price="20.00",
            image="django",
        )
        self.client.post(
            reverse("store_basket:basket_add"),
            {"productid": 1, "productqty": 1, "action": "post"},
            xhr=True,
        )
        self.client.post(
            reverse("store_basket:basket_add"),
            {"productid": 2, "productqty": 2, "action": "post"},
            xhr=True,
        )

    def test_basket_url(self):
        """
        Test homepage response status
        """
        response = self.client.get(reverse("store_basket:basket_summary"))
        self.assertEqual(response.status_code, 200)

    def test_basket_add(self):
        """
        Test adding items to the basket
        """
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("store_basket:basket_add"),
            {"productid": 3, "productqty": 1, "action": "post"},
            xhr=True,
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {"qty": 4})
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("store_basket:basket_add"),
            {"productid": 2, "productqty": 1, "action": "post"},
            xhr=True,
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {"qty": 3})

    def test_basket_delete(self):
        """
        Test deleting items from the basket
        """
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("store_basket:basket_delete"),
            {"productid": 2, "action": "post"},
            xhr=True,
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {"qty": 1, "subtotal": "20.00"})

    def test_basket_update(self):
        """
        Test updating items from the basket
        """
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse("store_basket:basket_update"),
            {"productid": 2, "productqty": 1, "action": "post"},
            xhr=True,
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {"qty": 2, "subtotal": "40.00"})
```

But i run the test and got this error:

```
======================================================================
ERROR: test_basket_add (store_basket.test.test_views.TestBasketView.test_basket_add)
Test adding items to the basket
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/ecommerce/store_basket/test/test_views.py", line 63, in test_basket_add
    self.assertEqual(response.json(), {"qty": 4})
                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/ecommerce/venv/lib/python3.11/site-packages/django/test/client.py", line 823, in _parse_json
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: Content-Type header is "text/html; charset=utf-8", not "application/json"

======================================================================
FAIL: test_basket_delete (store_basket.test.test_views.TestBasketView.test_basket_delete)
Test deleting items from the basket
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/ecommerce/store_basket/test/test_views.py", line 80, in test_basket_delete
    self.assertEqual(response.json(), {"qty": 1, "subtotal": "20.00"})
AssertionError: {'qty': 0, 'subtotal': 0} != {'qty': 1, 'subtotal': '20.00'}
- {'qty': 0, 'subtotal': 0}
?         ^

+ {'qty': 1, 'subtotal': '20.00'}
?         ^              ++ ++++


======================================================================
FAIL: test_basket_update (store_basket.test.test_views.TestBasketView.test_basket_update)
Test updating items from the basket
----------------------------------------------------------------------
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/bottgabriel/Desktop/Practices/py/ecommerce/store_basket/test/test_views.py", line 91, in test_basket_update
    self.assertEqual(response.json(), {"qty": 2, "subtotal": "40.00"})
AssertionError: {'qty': 0, 'subtotal': 0} != {'qty': 2, 'subtotal': '40.00'}
- {'qty': 0, 'subtotal': 0}
?         ^

+ {'qty': 2, 'subtotal': '40.00'}
?         ^              ++ ++++


----------------------------------------------------------------------
Ran 13 tests in 0.267s

FAILED (failures=2, errors=1, skipped=1)
Destroying test database for alias 'default'...
```

Any help will be much appreciated!

P.S: I have debugged and made sure that the view is returning a Json, but for some reason the test is not working.

Comment: your database will revert back to setup state for each test (ie your previous Add test will not carry onto your delete test) ... you should probably look into "fixtures"

Answer (score 1):

The most likely scenario is that the view raised an error, for example because the product did not exist, and that the middleware turned this into a HTML page.

It is a common misconception that the primary keys are fixed. They are not. You should store these in the testcase, so:

```
class TestBasketView(TestCase):
    def setUp(self):
        category = Category.objects.create(name='django', slug='django')
        user = User.objects.create(username='admin')
        self.product1 = Product.objects.create(
            title='django beginners',
            category=category,
            created_by=user,
            slug='django-beginners',
            price='20.00',
            image='django',
        )
        self.product2 = Product.objects.create(
            title='django intermediate',
            category=category,
            created_by=user,
            slug='django-beginners',
            price='20.00',
            image='django',
        )
        self.product3 = Product.objects.create(
            title='django advanced',
            category=category,
            created_by=user,
            slug='django-beginners',
            price='20.00',
            image='django',
        )
        self.client.post(
            reverse('store_basket:basket_add'),
            {'productid': self.product1.pk, 'productqty': 1, 'action': 'post'},
            xhr=True,
        )
        self.client.post(
            reverse('store_basket:basket_add'),
            {'productid': self.product1.pk, 'productqty': 2, 'action': 'post'},
            xhr=True,
        )

    def test_basket_add(self):
        """
        Test adding items to the basket
        """
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('store_basket:basket_add'),
            {'productid': self.product3.pk, 'productqty': 1, 'action': 'post'},
            xhr=True,
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {'qty': 4})
        response = self.client.post(
            reverse('store_basket:basket_add'),
            {'productid': self.product2.pk, 'productqty': 1, 'action': 'post'},
            xhr=True,
        )
        self.assertEqual(response.json(), {'qty': 3})
```

---

> **Note**: Normally one is *not* supposed to call magic attributes like `__len__`, normally this should only be done in certain circumstances, for example when working with a `super` call.